# Django objects and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, django, django-models, multiprocessing

I'm attempting to pull a whole host of info as quickly as possible and have the following code to assist in it:

```
pool = Pool()
products = Post.objects.filter(affiliate_product_url=None)
res = pool.map_async(get_info, products)
w = res.get()
pool.close()
```

When ran it returns a

```
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "scripts/image_affiliate_pull.py", line 113, in <module>
    w = res.get()
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

From my searching this may have to do with pickling? How would I best go about making it work? An explanation for why it works this way would be invaluable too :D

Comment: The `TypeError` is being thrown in `get_info`. Because of a limitation of `multiprocessing`, you don't get the traceback from `get_info` in the parent, though. Wrap `get_info` in a `try`/`except` block and call `traceback.print_exc()` inside the `except` block to see the real traceback. It should help you figure out what's actually wrong.

Comment: I added it. I know that get_info works because I am able to run it flawlessly by calling the function linearly with `[get_info(p) for p in Post.objects.filter(affiliate_product_url=None)]`, so I assumed it was purely a multiprocessing/map_async problem. What do you think?

Comment: The exception is *definitely* coming from `get_info`. The line that's raising the exception is the section of `ApplyResult.get` that raises the exception object that was returned from the child process. You need to print the full traceback in the child process itself to find out where the failure is actually happening. There's an object you're trying to access in `get_info` that isn't set in the child process. What platform are you running this on? Are you trying to use any global variables in `get_info`?

Comment: If getting a traceback is an issue, then I would try, even for debugging sake, to use multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool instead of the regular process pool. Possible caveat - not sure how the threads going to behave inside the web server.

Comment: @itai That worked! If you answer the question I'll mark it as the answer if you'd like. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad I've managed to help :) Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If getting a traceback is an issue, then for debugging sake you could use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead of the regular process pool. 
It has exactly the same interface, only you dont have the issue of passing tracebacks between the processes.

Possible caveat - not sure how the threads going to behave inside the web server.